# When I click on the button, the value of that button needs to add up to sum

Tags: javascript, html, pos

I was trying to code a POS like system as a small project to learn with.
So currently I have two buttons "cola" and "fanta". The prices of those drinks are in an object.
As soon as I click on one button the price needs to be added to sum.
Well what the code is currently doing is to add up the prices of the same product.
So if I click three times in a row on "cola", which has a price of 3, I get 9 as sum. So far so good, but as soon as I click fanta, which has a price of 2, I get a sum of 2. But when I continue with the cola button it continues at 12 and so on.

Here is the code:

```
  const btnChoose = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");

  const drinks= {
    cola: 4,
    fanta: 3,
  };

  for (let i = 0; i < btnChoose.length; i++) {
    let sum = null;
    btnChoose[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
      let price = drinks[this.id];
      sum += price;
      console.log(typeof sum, sum);
    });
  }
```

and here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>POS</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <button class="btn" id="cola">Cola</button>
    <button class="btn" id="fanta">Fanta</button>
    <script>
     ....
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `let sum=null` statement creates a separate locally scoped variable each pass through the `for` loop. Simply move the statement outside the for loop to then have only one sum variable.

```
  let sum=null;
  for (let i = 0; i < btnChoose.length; i++) {
```

fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/cLrao8fu/

Answer (score 1):

Sum is product wise because you have declared the variable sum inside the loop. If you move it outside of the loop like below you should get a sum which incorporates sum of all product values.

```
let sum = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < btnChoose.length; i++) {
    let price = 0;
    btnChoose[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
      price = drinks[this.id];
      sum += price;
      console.log(typeof sum, sum);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

its because you are defining sum in the loop
define it outside of the loop:

```
const btnChoose = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");

  const drinks= {
    cola: 4,
    fanta: 3,
  };

  let sum = null;

  for (let i = 0; i < btnChoose.length; i++) {
    btnChoose[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
      let price = drinks[this.id];
      sum += price;
      console.log(typeof sum, sum);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

that is because you are declaring the variable "sum" inside the loop, so each one will get a unique "sum". What you need to do is to have them both share 1 variable "sum", so intead of this:

```
  const btnChoose = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");

  const drinks= {
    cola: 4,
    fanta: 3,
  };

  for (let i = 0; i < btnChoose.length; i++) {
    let sum = null;
    btnChoose[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
      let price = drinks[this.id];
      sum += price;
      console.log(typeof sum, sum);
    });
  }
```

do this:

```
  const btnChoose = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");

  const drinks= {
    cola: 4,
    fanta: 3,
  };
  let sum = null; // moved it up here
  for (let i = 0; i < btnChoose.length; i++) {
    // moved it away from here
    btnChoose[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
      let price = drinks[this.id];
      sum += price;
      console.log(typeof sum, sum);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```javascript
let sum = 0;
const btnChoose = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");

const drinks = {
  cola: 4,
  fanta: 3,
};

for (let i = 0; i < btnChoose.length; i++) {
  btnChoose[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    let price = drinks[this.id];
    sum += price;
    console.log(typeof sum, sum);
  });
}
```